# Overriding styles.css in angular component for Boostrap navbar

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4

Trying to change the color of the app's navbar when a certain page is visited. The navbar is defined in the app.component.html file and I am trying to override it in a component's css file.

app.component.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
```

component.css

```
:host .navbar{
  background-color: orange !important;
}
```

Expected navbar to change to orange when component is visited. Component in this case is a page in the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#host), try:

```
:host(.navbar) {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

You shouldn't need the `!important` part of the style. Adding the styles in the stylesheet as you have above will scope them very specifically overriding those from the bootstrap stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Your app.component is an higher component compared to the other component created, so let your styling be done in your app.component.css